# Duplicate record handling in Sql*Loader

Tags: sql, loader

I want to add a check for duplicate record inserting in a table using sql loader.

For eg: while inserting rows in a table if it found a duplicate record, it should go for a condition.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: What sort of condition?  The specifics of what you're attempting are unclear.  At the minimum, you will want a unique key on the specified columns.  Which RDBMS - there may be vendor-specific options available.  Is 'SQL*Loader' a tool, or just a generic description of what you're using?

Answer (score 1):

```
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE your condition"; //like name='"+textbox.text+"'";
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
        da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) // Means data already present
        {
            lblmsg.Text = "This data is already added!";
        }
        else if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
              // Insert your value
        }
```

Comment: -1 This isn't safe in the face of concurrent access to the system, and should be avoided when possible - you'd have to lock the entire table.  Attempting an `INSERT` is safer-ish (assuming a unique key), but some SQL dialects have better options available.  Also, you're simply concatenating strings from the user into the query, which leaves you wonderfully open to SQL Injection - this should otherwise be a parameterized query.